# Huawei server oid not showing | RH2288

Tags: snmp, snmpd

I am having Huawei RH2288 V3 server for which I am trying to set up monitoring via Zabbix. I found the Mibs of same Huawei server, and while doing snmptranslate i am getting OID

```
snmptranslate -On HUAWEI-SERVER-IBMC-MIB::memoryStatus
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.2.235.1.1.16.50.1.6
```

but at the same time when i am trying to hit below command, i am getting "No Such Object available on this agent at this OID"

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 10.143.63.35 .1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.2.235.1.1.16.50.1.6
HUAWEI-SERVER-IBMC-MIB::memoryStatus = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

I have spend much time in doing google for same but not get any result.

Comment: try to go iteratively up within OID tree like `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 10.143.63.35 .1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.2.235.1.1` to see what actual MIB contains

Comment: Also, make sure those OIDs are accessible to `public` or try to grab a better community string. [These](http://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000157053?section=j006&topicName=security-management#bmc_user_0301_mMcCpPsS_tab_001) seems to be the defaults.

Comment: Thanks for the rkosegi and Luis: I ran the command snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 10.143.63.35 .1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.2.235.1.1
HUAWEI-SERVER-IBMC-MIB::hwiBMC = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID. However, I have found that by default snmp3 version is enabled by default. Can you please help in know how can i get the username & password of default snmp3 so that i can get the Odis

Comment: There is no "username & password of default snmp3" You need to ask the administrator how the server is configured (or, if you are the administration, read the documentation to find out how to configure it).

Comment: That the object is defined in the MIB doesn't mean it currently has a value on one particular agent. We can probably not answer this from here.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz If an agent is responding to a request for a valid object from an unauthorised manager with `noSuchObject` it is somewhat misconfigured. Though I guess I can see some agents doing that deliberately for modern security reasons ("don't admit something exists to those who should not be able to see it"), it's non-compliant.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Actually, looking at RFC 3416 4.2.1 it may be compliant